# an object reference is required to access non-static member

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok, so Im not very good at C# programming, so this is probably a dumb question.
I have my hands on a game made by someone else, and he had a Slogan thing. I changed the slogan to a list of slogans that are picked at random, no longer making it static.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameVersion : MonoBehaviour {

public const float AsFloat = 0.6f;
public const string AsString = "alpha v0.2.5";
public string Slogan = randomSlogan[new Random().Next(0,randomSlogan.Length) ];
string randomSlogan = {
    "3000",
    "bananas",
    "now with sand"
};

}
```

However, I receive the error "an object reference is required to access non-static member 'Gameversion.Slogan'", which I'm putting here

```
    GUI.Box(pos,"");
    GUILayout.BeginArea(pos);
    //Game version and slogan
    GUIStyle version = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.label);
    version.fontSize = 60;
    version.fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;
    GUILayout.Label(GameVersion.AsString,version);
    GUILayout.Label(GameVersion.Slogan); //Right here.
```

Ive seen other results with the same problem, but I've been having a hard time putting it into my code. Could anyone please come up with a solution that fits here? Thank you!

Also, sorry if I am posting to little or to much code!

Comment: Obviously you need to use a reference to a `GameVersion` instance, as that field is not static

Comment: You should probably make a `Random` instance variable and use that to return a random slogan; `new Random().Next` isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your class static or make an instance of the GameVersion class:

```
GameVersion instance = new GameVersion();
GUILayout.Label(instance.Slogan);
```

Making the instance is usually preferable in my experience.

Comment: "Just making an instance" is *rarely* the right answer. That instance usually comes from somewhere else.

Comment: You are right, but I'm just trying to give a quick and dirty answer to this question that has probably been asked thousands of times.  He can go look at those for detailed reasoning.